# Can I put all the space between two elements in a flex box or grid?

Tags: html, css

I have a header that looks like this:

```html
<header>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
</header>
```

Rather than spacing these items evenly, I want all the space to be between A and B, like this:

[image: Demonstration]

**Is there any way to do this with plain CSS, without adding extra wrapper elements in HTML?**

---

I'm very specifically talking about *spacing*, adding `flex-grow: 1` to `A` is cheating  In my case both `A` and `B` are clickable, and I don't want them smeared across the entire header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some basic solutions I can think of:

For a `flex` container, use `margin-right: auto` on "A".

For a `grid` container, set `grid-template-column: 1fr repeat(2, min-content)` so that "A" will be placed at the `1fr` column.

Example:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  outline: 3px solid #666;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
}

header>div:first-of-type {
  margin-right: auto;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  outline: 3px solid #666;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, min-content);
}
```

```html
<h3> Flex container</h3>
<header>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</header>

<h3> Grid container </h3>
<main>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</main>
```

And here are some of everyone's favorite weird solutions I can think of, this example uses pseudo element as a spacer (not recommended, just to show the possibility):

For a `flex` container, specify `order` for the pseudo element spacer to have it placed after "A".

For a `grid` container, specify the pseudo element spacer to take the desired column, so that auto placement can cover the other elements.

Example:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  outline: 3px solid #666;
}

header::before {
  content: "I'm a pseudo spacer";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: large;
  order: 2;
  flex: 1;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
}

header > div {
  order: 3;
}

header > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 1;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  width: 400px;
  outline: 3px solid #666;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr repeat(2, min-content);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

main::before {
  content: "I'm a pseudo spacer";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: large;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<h3> Flex but with pseudo element as spacer</h3>
<header>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</header>

<h3> Grid but with pseudo element as spacer</h3>
<main>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `margin-left:auto;` to `B` to have it move across. You can see more examples [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-auto-margins-work-in-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:red;
  align-items:center;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px
}

.container div {
  height:90px;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:green;
  width:90px;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:15px;
  text-align:center;
}

.container .B {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```